# Powershell DSC ConfigurationData keys

Tags: powershell, dsc

I'm new to DSC and just trying to understand some basic concept around configuration data.  I understand that you can pass dynamic config data into your configuration.  I'm also now able to encrypt credentials using a certificate by passing in the CertificateFile key into the AllNodes variable of the config data.

I'm just trying to understand how this is applied.  I was under the impression that the config data just allowed you present dynamic data for the configuration to use.  Does this mean that if, for some bizarre reason, I wanted to hardcode the certificatefile into the configuration, rather than in the config data, I could do so?

Or can this only be applied via ConfigData? If so, are there other "system" keys that can be applied to config data? I've not been able to find any documentation online that explains this.

Example config data:

```
$ConfigData=    @{
    AllNodes = @(     
                    @{  
                        NodeName = "MYSERVER"
                        CertificateFile = "C:\MyPublicKey.cer"
                    };
                );    
}
```

There is nothing in the main configuration that seems to expect the key "CertificateFile."

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By using the built-in DSC ConfigurationData parameter, you can define data that can be used within a configuration. This allows you to create a single configuration that can be used for multiple nodes or for different environments. For example, if you are developing an application, you can use one configuration for both development and production environments, and use configuration data to specify data for each environment.

Reference:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2014/01/09/separating-what-from-where-in-powershell-dsc/
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/configdata

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I get that.  I've seen those posts as well and I've got it all working.  I can pass in, for example UserNameA and then reference it in the configuration as $Node.UserNameA.  

But as for ConfigurationFile, this is a key that I pass in with no $Node.ConfigurationFile in the configuration.  It seems as if it's a "system" variable of some sort.  I don't have to refer to a configurationFile in the configuration.